# Symfony5: form processing on all templates

Tags: forms, symfony5

I want a form on all templates. For the display, I have no worries. I use a controller, and I integrate the action into the base template (often base.html.twig). Here is the action of the controller:

```
public function showForm(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(LetsTalkType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    return $this->render('_lets_talk.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

And here is the integration into the template:

```
{{render(controller('App\\Controller\\LetsTalkController::showForm')) }}
```

The problem is that for each controller (PostController, ServiceController, PortfolioController, etc.) I have to add a piece of code to check if the form is sent and valid and then call the action of the LestsTalkController controller like this below:

```
  public function show($slug, Request $request,  LetsTalkController $letsTalkController, MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        
        $letsTalk = new LetsTalk();
        $letsTalkForm = $this->createForm(LetsTalkType::class);
        $letsTalkForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($letsTalkForm->isSubmitted() && $letsTalkForm->isValid()) {
                $letsTalkController->sendEmail($letsTalkForm, $request, $mailer);
        }
}
```

Isn't there a solution to avoid writing code on all controllers?
Thank you for your reply :).

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to set the action for the form to send it to a single controller/action

```
<?php
class ContactFormController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/contact-form", name="contact_form")
     */
    public function index(Request $request = null, EmailService $email)
    {
        $formEntity = new LetsTalk();
        $form = $this->createForm(LetsTalkType::class, $formEntity, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('contact_form'), // set action here to post form to
            'method' => 'POST',
        ]);
        
        if (null !== $request && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $formEntity = $form->getData();

                ...

                $email->sendNewContact($formEntity); // or watever
                
                return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer')); // redirect to previous page
            }
        }

        return $this->render('_lets_talk.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then you can render the form as you do

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but letstalk is on all the templates, it is an overlay which opens after a click on a button. The form does not have a url intended for it.

Comment: @a_zero I understand. I'm using forms on all pages too, but it's better to send them to the same dedicated controller to avoid adding form handling to all your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I put it below because it could be useful for people who are in the same situation. For the inclusion of the controller in the template:

```
{{render(controller('App\\Controller\\LetsTalkController::letsTalkForm', {request: app.request})) }}
```